# Why is there a difference in Training Accuracy Output, when the training dataset is the same but the validation dataset is different?

Tags: deep-learning, training, accuracy, model-evaluations, image-segmentation

I am looking at the output of a multi-class image segmentation deep learning model. I used U-Net to implement this.

I am confused about why the training accuracies are different for a different validation dataset when using the same training dataset and exactly the SAME model.

Note: The hyperparameters are set as same for both cases.
a) Adams optimizer: lr = 0.001
b) batch size = 1 (Yes, I know I will need to use a bigger batch size; this is only a test)
c) epoch = 1000

The only difference is
a) Augmented uses 48 images for validation
b) Pseudo-Augmented use of 2 images for validation.

Thank you in advance.

The output is shown below. [image]

Comment: Hi @user10529827, welcome to the site. Are these differences consistent across multiple runs?

Comment: @noe Yes, they are very similar. Does the validation dataset (size) affect the training accuracies?

Comment: No, but the randomness does. I was thinking that maybe the results were not consistent across runs due to different parameter initializations.

Comment: @noe Thank you for your answer. What do you mean by the randomness? The randomness of the data split? I have a random seeding set to a variable, so the dataset is consistent between the two different sets.

Comment: There are multiple sources of randomness: the data split, the training data ordering, the weight initialization and other elements (e.g. dropout).